# Bounding geometry convex hull

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, concave-hull

I have huge point clouds (Millions of points):

[image: point cloud]

I need to create a shapefile with the boundary of this point cloud. When I was working with this 2 months ago I could do this somehow:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I was using the Minimum Bounding Geometry with the convex hull option. But when I try to recreate it I get the following result:

[image]

I've been trying to figure out what did I do differently, but no luck yet.

I have ArcGIS 10.2 with advanced license.

Comment: Use concave hull toolbox by @Richard fond in https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/06/11/bruce-harolds-concave-hull-estimator-tool-enhanced

Comment: It seems this tool is very slow. It's running for an hour now.

Comment: Another thing to try is creating TIN and delineating it, i.e. removing long sides on perimeter

Comment: TIN method doesn't work. I ran out of memory (16GB)

Comment: Very dirty. Export view as image with world file. Convert result to grid and export to polygon. Try different resolution for export

Answer (score 1):

You can try Aggregate Points tool (Cartography Tools / Generalization). It will cluster your points based on user-given distance, so you have to know the dispersion of your point FC to define a very good one.